# unable to access CouchDB web GUI (OSX)

Tags: macos, nosql, couchdb, couchdb-futon

Hello I just installed couchDB on my MacBook Pro

I installed it using MacPort

```
sudo port install couchdb
sudo port upgrade couchdb
sudo launchctl load -w /opt/local/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.couchdb.plist
org.apache.couchdb: Already loaded
```

But I'm unable to access the web GUI http://localhost:5984/_utils/index.html

what should I do to be able to access the web GUI?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same problem after updating to *MacPorts 1.9.2*.

There is an [issue with erlang from Mac ports and couchdb](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1106?focusedCommentId=13021617&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-13021617). To fix it:

1.Uninstall erlang (optional - you can keep it as inactive)

```
sudo port uninstall erlang
```

2.Install erlang with the `+ssl` variant

```
sudo port install erlang +ssl
```

That should do the trick without the need to touch your couchdb installation:) **Time to relax.**

Comment: Added info about it to http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_OSX .

What is strange to me is that the `./configure && make` from couchdb dont inform about the missing component however running tests by `make check` results in fail.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use the [OSX Desktopcouch](http://www.couchone.com/get#mac) or just sign up for a free instance at [couchone?](http://www.couchone.com/get)

Comment: Whats the -1 for?